# Get request getting cancelled from iframe

Tags: javascript, java, spring-mvc, iframe, payment

I have a hosted payment page which we load inside an iframe.

At the end, when the transaction completes, the payment provider uses a url provided by us in the iframe so that we can break out of iframe or do whatever we need after the transaction is complete.

Now I am facing an issue which I can't really figure out.

[image]

The payment provider (inside the iframe once transaction is complete) does try to send the request to the url that we have setup, but the request gets cancelled due to the following reason :

**Mixed Content: The page at 'https://www.local..........' was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure form action 'http://www.local........../complete?ref=95b0bb87-dsfg'. This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS.**

Now I think it might be because of iframe but have no clue what that error means or how could I resolve it.

FYI, this was in chrome browser.

Comment: Take a look at this: http://blog.heyo.com/iframe-issue-mixed-content/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally figured out the solution.

As I am using Spring MVC, there are interceptors for spring security which were configured for handling requests for `HTTP` and `HTTPS`.

Since, I added this new controller to handle the request from the url that was set up for the payment provider response, it was missing the configuration in the spring security xml file.

So all I had to do was to add the required configuration in spring security xml file for the url that I have configured and then it started properly using the `HTTPS` url which ultimately solved the `Mixed Content` issue for my problem.